# Jdeps and war archives

Tags: java, war, jdeps

Is it possible to run Jdeps on a .war file?

I get this error when trying:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.classfile.Dependencies$ClassFileError
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ClassFileReader.scan(ClassFileReader.java:165)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ClassFileReader.entries(ClassFileReader.java:114)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Archive.contains(Archive.java:95)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.addRoot(JdepsConfiguration.java:495)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:597)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:557)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.classfile.ConstantPool$InvalidIndex: invalid index #13907
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.classfile.ConstantPool.get(ConstantPool.java:269)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.classfile.ConstantPool.get(ConstantPool.java:280)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.classfile.ConstantPool.getClassInfo(ConstantPool.java:291)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.classfile.ClassFile.getName(ClassFile.java:123)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ClassFileReader.scan(ClassFileReader.java:162)
```

Comment: How did you run jdeps on your file?

Comment: I run "jdeps -v myFile.war" with java 11.

Comment: I do not believe you can run this on a .war file. See the [tools page on the jdeps command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdeps.html) that explicitly states "A pathname to the .class file, directory, or JAR file to analyze." and "package-level or class-level dependencies".

Comment: I was thinking that there might be a chance he would take it into account, but that didn't seem to be possible. Thank you